# Showing individual elements of list on site

Tags: list, list-view, site-template

I am completely new to Sharepoint, but I need to make something:

I have a list in my group, and one of the columns in that group is a Choice column. That is to categorize each element in that list. How can I make a site in which I only show elements from one category? Also, I want to pick and choose which columns I show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is creating views. [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) is some information on that.
The way you would go about creating your view is by adding a filter condition that matches the column and the value to it.

Cheers and happy SharePointing!

Answer (score 1):

I would add to what Tanmay said by saying that you could also set up a view that filters on a name e.g. for a Task List.

In the List Settings select either `Create View` or `Modify View`.  If you are creating a new view, scroll down through the available columns until you come to the `Filter` heading - then in the name column (TaskAssignedTo) set the filter to [Me].  The new view will filter on the user who is logged in - you will see your own tasks, your colleague will see their own tasks.

`[Me]` = a sort of dynamic username filter.

Also check out the `Group By` feature in list settings.  You can group items (or tasks) by the Category and then by a User Name field.  This will present a useful summary views, especially useful when there are lots of categories or users.

Since you are just starting to use Sharepoint, I don't know if you are the Administrator or a user, but this blog has a [useful post on columns](http://sharepointmaven.com/shall-create-list-column-site-column/) - columns can be added at the List level (local tier) or at the site level (higher tier).  This is a really useful blog by the way, it is a favourite of mine.

Comment: Well, one final question: How do I post a particular view on a site? I know how I can post the entire list, but not one specific view of the list.

Comment: I think you mean a List rather than a Site.  To show all List items you would not use any filters.  If you think how a database works, a SP List is similar.  e.g. Show me all Categories (unfiltered).  Show me only Category A - this would be a separate view.  If you want to see only Category B - this would be an additional view.  It sounds like you might want to have multiple views.  I suggest keeping the default view showing all Categories.  Then 'CREATE VIEW' and configure a new view with a Filter - Select the Category multi-choice column and select a value e.g. Category A.

Comment: A 'view' is simply a pre-set filter of your items.  A view can be shared by all users (if you want it to be) or you can set up a personal view for your own use.

Comment: No, I mean a site. I have a list, and I want sites that show just parts of that list. So, I define a view, and I display that view on a site. Right now I only know how to put the entire list on a site, and not a view.

Comment: You can change the default view which all users will see, the filters will filter out other columns that you might not wish to display to them.  You could also explore using Web Parts to display list information too.  If it is sensitive information you are handling (e.g. Accounts or Payroll) then you'll need to be careful and perhaps use a different approach.